# Confluent RabbitMQ Source Connector - configuration, license related error?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, aws-msk

our Kafka setup consists of brokers on AWS MSK, Confluent Kafka Connect (confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.1) on AWS EKS pod.

We are trying to use Confluent RabbitMQ Source Connector (trial version of commercial connector) https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.1/connect/kafka-connect-rabbitmq/index.html and getting below error .

Connector Config -

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
  "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "b-1.###.amazonaws.com:9092, b-2.###.amazonaws.com:9092,b-3.###.amazonaws.com:9092,b-4.###.amazonaws.com:9092",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "rabbitmq.password": "user",
  "rabbitmq.queue": "my_queue",
  "rabbitmq.username": "pass",
  "rabbitmq.virtual.host": "/",
  "rabbitmq.port": "port",
  "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1",
  "rabbitmq.host": "rabbit_host_ip",
  "name": "Rabbit_Source_RT4",
  "kafka.topic": "my_topic",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"
}
```

GET Connector Status -

```
{
  "name": "Rabbit_Source_RT4,
  "connector": {
    "state": "FAILED",
    "worker_id": "kfk-connect:8083",
    "trace": "java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat io.confluent.license.License.readFully(License.java:195)\n\tat io.confluent.license.License.loadPublicKey(License.java:187)\n\tat io.confluent.license.License.loadPublicKey(License.java:181)\n\tat io.confluent.license.LicenseManager.loadPublicKey(LicenseManager.java:553)\n\tat io.confluent.license.LicenseManager.registerOrValidateLicense(LicenseManager.java:331)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.utils.licensing.ConnectLicenseManager.registerOrValidateLicense(ConnectLicenseManager.java:257)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector.doStart(RabbitMQSourceConnector.java:62)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector.start(RabbitMQSourceConnector.java:56)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:110)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:135)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.transitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:195)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startConnector(Worker.java:259)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startConnector(DistributedHerder.java:1229)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1300(DistributedHerder.java:127)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$14.call(DistributedHerder.java:1245)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$14.call(DistributedHerder.java:1241)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"
  },
  "tasks": [],
  "type": "source"
}
```

Connector state failed and no task created. Also tried to update this configuration, but same error everytime.

Logs -

```
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,884] INFO Kafka version: 5.5.1-ccs (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,884] INFO Kafka commitId: a0a0000zzz0a0000 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,884] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1610032877884 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,884] INFO [Producer clientId=Rabbit_Source_RT4-license-manager] Cluster ID: -aAaAzxcvA1a0weaaa11A (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,887] INFO [Consumer clientId=Rabbit_Source_RT4-license-manager, groupId=null] Cluster ID: -aAaAzxcvA1a0weaaa11A (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,890] INFO [Consumer clientId=Rabbit_Source_RT4-license-manager, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): _confluent-command-0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,890] INFO [Consumer clientId=Rabbit_Source_RT4-license-manager, groupId=null] Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition _confluent-command-0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,899] INFO [Consumer clientId=Rabbit_Source_RT4-license-manager, groupId=null] Resetting offset for partition _confluent-command-0 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,900] INFO Finished reading KafkaBasedLog for topic _confluent-command (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,900] INFO Started KafkaBasedLog for topic _confluent-command (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,900] INFO Started License Store (io.confluent.license.LicenseStore)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,901] INFO Validating Confluent License (io.confluent.connect.utils.licensing.ConnectLicenseManager)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,906] INFO Closing License Store (io.confluent.license.LicenseStore)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,906] INFO Stopping KafkaBasedLog for topic _confluent-command (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,908] INFO [Producer clientId=Rabbit_Source_RT4-license-manager] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,910] INFO Stopped KafkaBasedLog for topic _confluent-command (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,910] INFO Closed License Store (io.confluent.license.LicenseStore)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,910] ERROR WorkerConnector{id=Rabbit_Source_RT4} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.confluent.license.License.readFully(License.java:195)
        at io.confluent.license.License.loadPublicKey(License.java:187)
        at io.confluent.license.License.loadPublicKey(License.java:181)
        at io.confluent.license.LicenseManager.loadPublicKey(LicenseManager.java:553)
        at io.confluent.license.LicenseManager.registerOrValidateLicense(LicenseManager.java:331)
        at io.confluent.connect.utils.licensing.ConnectLicenseManager.registerOrValidateLicense(ConnectLicenseManager.java:257)
        at io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector.doStart(RabbitMQSourceConnector.java:62)
        at io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector.start(RabbitMQSourceConnector.java:56)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:110)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:135)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.transitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:195)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startConnector(Worker.java:259)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startConnector(DistributedHerder.java:1229)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1300(DistributedHerder.java:127)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$14.call(DistributedHerder.java:1245)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$14.call(DistributedHerder.java:1241)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,913] INFO Finished creating connector Rabbit_Source_RT4 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,913] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=compose-kfk-connect-group] Skipping reconfiguration of connector Rabbit_Source_RT4 since it is not running (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2021-01-07 15:21:17,913] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=compose-kfk-connect-group] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
```

Output of GET /connector-plugins request contains -

```
{"class":"io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"0.0.0.0"},
```

Also checked and found that '_confluent-command' topic does not contain any messages.

1. Is it because of trial version is over and an Enterprise license will be needed OR due to some error in configuration ?
2. How to verify duration remaining on trial version (since we are not using Control Center) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did anyone come across this issue in past ?